# Prompting the user to input a character

Tags: python

```
n = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]    
c = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
num = int (input())
char = int (input())
if n[num] % 2 == 0 and c[char] % 2 == 0 or n[num] % 2 != 0 and c[char] % 2 != 0:
    print("Black") 
else: 
    print("White")
```

I am currently working on a problem which is supposed to print out the color of the tile, according to the coordinates that the user inputs. I am very new to python and have no idea how to initialize a character input from the user. It needs to be in the range of a - h and be set to numbers from 1 to 8. Can you hint me a way to do this?

Comment: What happens when you run that code, and what is it doing (so far)?

Comment: You enter 2 integers and it prints what color that specific tile is. But the problem is that the second input needs to be a character (from a to h) and the program needs to convert that character into an integer from 1 to 8 to be able to go through the conditions and print the result.

Comment: Well you shouldn't attempt it in one step with `int(input())`. Get the input character first then, as a subsequent step, attempt to obtain an integer for it.

Comment: @Vahan all you need to do is convert the character to its ordinal value. For example,
`char = input(); charvalue = ord(char) - ord('a')`

Comment: @Andy G Yeah of course, but how to prompt the user to input a character? Like in c++ you write char x; then cin >> x;

Comment: Python's `input()` function goes line by line. So you'd have to handle it in that way, unless you want to do a custom I/O routine.

Comment: There are many examples on line of prompting the user for input.  We expect you to do individual research before coming here to ask a question.

Comment: In particular, if you look into using a tkinter dropdown menu, called a combobox. This will give your user only the options you want to be allowed. https://www.delftstack.com/tutorial/tkinter-tutorial/tkinter-combobox/

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for user input by putting an `input` call where you need to
ask things.

```
number = input("Choose a number between 1 and 10\n")
print("You chose ", number)
```

but then the input will be only things that the user can type (strings)
so you have to be careful and validate the choice

```
raw_number = input("Choose a number between 1 and 10\n")
number = int(raw_number, 10)
if number >= 0  and number <= 10:
    print("The next number is ", number + 1)
else:
    print("You clearly did not read the instructions!")
```

And again it could be that the choice the user made is not even a number

```
raw_number = input("Choose a number between 1 and 10\n")
try:
   number = int(raw_number, 10)
except ValueError:
   print("I said a number! You gave me " raw_number)
   exit(1)
if number >= 0  and number <= 10:
    print("The next number is ", number + 1)
else:
    print("You clearly did not read the instructions!")
```

but maybe you really need a number and want to patiently wait for a user

```
number = None
while not number:
    raw_number = input("Choose a number between 1 and 10\n")
    try:
        number = int(raw_number, 10)
    except ValueError:
        print("I said a number! You gave me ", raw_number, " try again!")
if number >= 0  and number <= 10:
    print("The next number is ", number + 1)
else:
    print("You clearly did not read the instructions!")
```